# what is -> operator?

Tags: if-statement, data-structures, discrete-mathematics

oops, I am not talking about Object Operator, some call it arrow, some call it thingy...

today, while studying **DISCRETE STRUCTURES**, teacher told us,

`if p then q` , this is a conditional statement and its written as `p -> q` ( p implies q),

my question was, what this sign is called, teacher says its if and then sign, then say, its implies sign, but I dont feel it right...

can somebody tell me what this sign is called?? can somebody explain it ? as I was caught in the sign only, I wasnt even able to listen what the teacher was telling about this conditional statement...( teacher sent me out of class saying  YOU ARE ASKING FOOLISH QUESTIONSS :(  )

One Request..I dont know where to Put this question...as discrete structures relates to programming, so putting my question right here, Forgive me for this if I am at wrong place ( no down-voting , rather please shift this question to approperiate place )

Comment: when i was in place of you, i used to call it `drive` or `p drives q` .

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about discrete math and logic, which is more appropriate at math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I already told you people that I am not sure where to put this question, my reason for putting this question here was that discrete logic relates to programming, so question should be here..sorry as I seem to be wrong..can somebody please edit this to meet the programming standards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wikipedia titles it the **[Material Conditional](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_conditional)** operator, though I've usually called it the **implication** operator. In my discrete structures class, we generally read it as either "if p then q" or "p implies q".

For completeness sake, here's the truth table:

```
p | q | p -> q
--------------
T | T |   T
T | F |   F
F | T |   T
F | F |   T
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could call it simply the arrow sign. We used to say it like "p arrow q".

Answer (score 0):

you can understand it by this way,

```
p -> q // p derives q. You can reach to q if you are given p.
       // q is obtainable from p.
```